# Updating client model without a full refresh

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to add records to a client `model` and indicate to Ember that these records are already on the server side?

So, for instance if my `Person` model has records for "Peter" and "Paul" but then later the server adds "Mary" and my client becomes aware of that in a non ember-data sort of way. I'd like to be able to have the client add "Mary" in a way that will not cause state problems with the subsequent interactions.

For those that must know the "use case" ... I'm trying to:

- have the first request to findAll() for a given `model` to pull the full set of data back from the server
- have subsequent requests in a session call a custom AJAX request that only returns differences to the resultset since that last request
- I want to be able to push these differences into the client model without screwing up it's "state"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes we create and update EmberData records on the client with data from websockets. In this case, the changes are already on the server, so we just want to make the changes on the client without changing state, etc, exactly as you describe.

When we create new records on the client, we `push` them into the store, e.g.:

```
this.store.push('post', { id: 1, body: 'Ember!' });
```

And, when we update existing records on the client, we `update` them in the store, e.g.:

```
this.store.update('post', { id: 1, hidden: true });
```

Comment: Great, thanks. BTW, I am looking forward to finding some time to get some websockets into my application. Two quick questions ... I don't see an `update()` method on `store`. Am I missing something? Also, wrt to your "push" example, just wanted to validate that in the "push" use case you're talking about a situation where a new record is added on the server, notification to the client takes place via websockets, and then the "push" achieves the same result on the client side. Is that right?

Comment: @ken (1) `update` is a method on `store` in the latest versions of EmberData (2) you are correct

Comment: (1) Ok, I see it in the code. It's not made the documentation yet.